# Content width is more than the body width?

Tags: html, css

Here is a much-simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/MmcEY/3/
The body width is artificially rejected here, though it's not the case for the real app - see below.

There are multiple blocks laid out similar to #d1 and #d2. All of them having min-width set.
There's also a stripe at the bottom of the screen that must fill the whole width.

On a wide screen everything works fine - there's enough of body width for blocks to fit, no scrolling and the stripe fills the whole screen width.

But on a narrow screen (emulated in the example with the body width explicitly set) the following happens: the content's width is actually more than the body's width. This content make the horizontal scrolling appear, though it doesn't stretch the body. So, the stripe (the green line at the bottom) occupies less space than the page content.

=====

Well, great, guys, I know it's because of margin :).

As I said, fixed body width is set here for demonstration only, in the real world the body width is defined by the window size. But several blocks are still outside of the body, so the scroll appears, while body width doesn't change.

So, is there any way **to make the stripe fill the whole window client width** while preserving the rest of markup?

I'm working with the existing site, and don't want completely re-hacking the whole layout (quite complicated and not coded by me).

Comment: Can you give a link to the site then please? It'd help people to see this in action.

Comment: I tried to omit this with minimal example. I should probably create a better one, tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `#d2` element has a negative `margin-right` set — which means that it's going to fall outside the `body` element. If you remove this property then you'll see that the block falls down to the next line (as `#d1` and `#d2` are both `150px`).

Essentially, the layout is doing what you're telling it to do. The stripe is always `200px` wide (100% of the body width) regardless of browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the margin of -200px on the second div. This tricks the browser into thinking that it's -50px wide, so it will make those divs fit next to each other, even though part of this content renders outside the body.

So: lose the margin. :)

Comment: I see your update, but I don't see how it changes the answer. The minimal width of 150px is respected, meaning the second div would wrap to below if the body width shrinks below 300px. But it's that margin that keeps it from working. Also, if your body has any margins or paddings, setting the strip width to 100%, will cause it to be larger that the client size of the body. It will grow to the full width, including those margins. If you want it to fill up the body client width, you should skip the width on the stripe. By default it will fill up the space.

Comment: You could set min-width to 300px on the body itself to prevent it from being smaller. But I'm not exactly sure what you want it to look like. Do you want to make the stripe obey the min-width of 300px, or do you want to place the div2 below div1 when they don't fit next to each other?

Comment: it's just a sample, in the real situation there is min-width on body, but it's less than the sum of min-widths of the blocks.

I want the stripe to ignore the body width and take the full width of the window client area.

Now I'm thinking I should suggest guys increase body's min-width to match with the blocks real estate, but it won't probably reach the space taken by the negative margin

Comment: I think the best solution would be not to style the body at all. Put a div inside the body. You can style this in the way you style the body now. Then, you can put the outside that div (but still inside the body, of course) and style it to make it the full width of the body.

Comment: makes sense, have to check how critical can it be for the current layout (there are ~100 templates in a Django project, though they all inherit from a single base template)